# How can I center multiple divs on a page, and left-align them when a div drops to next row?

Tags: jquery, css, html, centering

I have a page with several "modules" made up of individual `<div>`s that are 159 px wide and 160 px high. The modules should form a centered row. The containing `<div>` is set to 70% width.

When the window is resized so that one or more of the modules drop to the next row, I want them to be left-aligned instead of centering the next row, so that you wouldn't see (for instance) four modules on top and one centered below them.

This means that using `text-align: center` is not an option, which is unfortunate because that centers them perfectly otherwise. With my current CSS they are kind of centered, but when one module drops down to the next row, the centering `<div>` does not resize back to the content width, so it is not perfectly centered. Is this something that can be resolved with CSS? If not, I'd be willing to use jQuery.

```
#modulesAreaBlock { /*Outer containing DIV*/
    margin-top: 50px;
    width:70%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#modulesCenter { /*DIV for centering the modules inside the outer DIV*/
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}

.moduleBlock { /*The individual "module" DIVs*/
    text-align:center;
    height: 160px;
    width: 159px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    _height: 160px;
}
```

Comment: I got it to work in IE8 by changing the modulesCenter DIV into a span, but in Chrome, Firefox and IE9 it still doesn't center properly.

Comment: I just answered a similar question to this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331150/center-fluid-grid-of-elements-without-setting-hard-width-on-parent/8332101#8332101

Comment: What a coincidence! That is pretty much exactly what I'm trying to do, only I'm not using a list. I'll see if I can adapt that to fit into my code.

Comment: OK, I set up a page with an example of how my site is set up: http://jsfiddle.net/9Qgsm/

Comment: @Scott Updated the link with more color to show how the centering div only centers when all module divs are on the same row: http://jsfiddle.net/9Qgsm/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Scott's idea (using placeholders) I was able to create this solution using jQuery and CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/9Qgsm/20/

Using just placeholders isn't good enough because when the window reaches a certain width everything will stay off-center. The jQuery allows the placeholders to appear or disappear according to the width of the containing div. The div width minimum can be set dynamically depending on how many modules there are in the div (I'll be doing that part with ColdFusion).

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    //If the div creates more than one row of modules, add dummy divs
    if ($('#modulesAreaBlock').width()<625){
        $('.dummy').css('display','inline-block');
    }
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    //If the div creates more than one row of modules, add dummy divs
    if ($('#modulesAreaBlock').width()<625){
        $('.dummy').css('display','inline-block');        
    }
    //If the width of containing div contains all modules, hide the dummies
        if ($('#modulesAreaBlock').width()>=625){
        $('.dummy').css('display','none');
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
#modulesAreaBlock {
    margin-top: 50px;
    width:70%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative; 
    text-align: center;
}

/*Displays the module blocks*/
.moduleBlock {
    text-align:center;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    _height: 160px;
}

.dummy{
    display:none;
    width:100px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try floating the modules left and setting their display to block instead of using inline-block. Inline-block is not very cross-browser friendly especially in IE.

Comment: Yes, same issue... they don't center exactly as soon as something drops to the next row.