# Center fluid grid of elements without setting hard width on parent

Tags: html, css

I'd like to center a 'grid' of elements that—when resized—adjusts to center itself.

Like this:

```
 ___________________
|                   |
|    [] [] [] []    |
|    [] [] [] []    |
|    [] [] []       |
 -------------------
 ________________
|                |
|    [] [] []    |
|    [] [] []    |
|    [] [] []    |
|    [] []       |
 ----------------
 _____________
|             |
|    [] []    |
|    [] []    |
|    [] []    |
|    [] []    |
|    [] []    |
|    []       |
 -------------
```

I've tried setting a `max-width`, but that leads to this problem when resized:

```
 ________________
|                |
|    [] [] []    |
|    [] [] []    |
|    [] [] []    |
|    [] []       |
 ----------------
 _____________
|             |
| [] []       |
| [] []       |
| [] []       |
| [] []       |
| [] []       |
| []          |
 -------------
```

I do not consider using media queries and setting hard `widths` (or even `max-widths`) for every configuration a real solution.

I am open to CSS3 as long as it degrades gracefully, and would like to avoid javascript.

**Edit:** Adding non-semantic elements is also a deal breaker, a container `div` or something would be passable but not ideal.

The markup should be as follows:

```
 <ul>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
 </ul>
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nR9Mk/) to get you started.

Thank you.

Comment: I really don't think there is a way to do what you are asking without using some javascript or jQuery

Comment: Added a solution based on your new requirements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's still a little vague as to what your exact requirements are for centering (as in, all your illustrations above show an even number of elements, so I don't know what you expect for odd number. In your fiddle, I just added a `text-align: center` to the `ul` and achieved a centering effect ( http://jsfiddle.net/nR9Mk/1/ ), but I don't know if it is behaving as you desire.

**Update**: If you are only dealing with even numbers and you want them to remain grouped by two's, then this would work: http://jsfiddle.net/nR9Mk/8/.

**ROUND 2**: Based on your revealed "odd number" requirements, I have come up with a solution that works. Note: 1) it does require some extra HTML markup, 2) you have to set some type of practical limit to how wide you want to go and still get the effect. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nR9Mk/41/) is the code with the "buffer" elements revealed by an `outline` and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nR9Mk/42/) is it with the outline removed.

**ROUND 3**: I know you already accepted my answer, but I was already working on this, so I figured I would offer it anyway. Based on your deal breaker comment, [here is a modified plan](http://jsfiddle.net/nR9Mk/121/) that may be useful for you (or someone else). It is a hybrid -- "sometimes" it pushes the elements left (usually when it would be most awkward to not) and sometimes lets them stay "off column" but centered. To keep it from ever looking plain "weird" it is given a `max-width` of six columns wide.

Comment: I updated my examples with odd numbers. The placement of the last row is not ideal and I am still looking for other solutions, but thank you.

Comment: Thanks. That definitely will require a different solution.

Comment: Scott, first of all, thank you so much for your input. +1, so you know. However, the extra elements are a deal breaker, I apologize for not specifying this in my answer. I also observed this [bug](http://i.imgur.com/CP6AI.png). Thanks again.

Comment: That's not really a "bug." As I said in my answer, you would have to set a practical limit to just how wide to go and still get the effect. Adding extra "buffers" would solve the "bug." May I ask why extra elements are a "deal breaker"?

Comment: I think I can live with the centering in your original solution. Adding extra `li` with nothing in them is a deal breaker because they are not list items, they are purely presentational. In the end, how different is using `li` like that and using `table`s for layout? It's important to describe the content semantically.

Comment: Okay. Some people are more concerned about semantic mark-up than others, so I can respect that. I did add a "Round 3" answer that is a pure css hybrid between the original answer and the round 2 answers. It may or may not satisfy you better, but take a look.