# Is it possible to have a div resize in increments?

Tags: jquery, css, html, resize

I have a centred div with floating elements in it, each element has the same height and width and is floating. When the div is resized, there is always a gap on the right side where there isnt enough space to fit another element. What I want is for the div to only expand when it can fit another element rather than just have a space there. Is that possible?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### CSS3 Solution

Using some `@media` query calls (so there is a practical limit to how large one might want to go), yields a good result on CSS3 browsers. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Xskq/8/) ([full screen](http://jsfiddle.net/2Xskq/8/embedded/result/)), which uses this (just for example) code:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="container">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 122px) {
  .container {width: 120px;}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 242px) {
  .container {width: 240px;}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 362px) {
  .container {width: 360px;}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 482px) {
  .container {width: 480px;}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 602px) { 
  .container {width: 600px;}
}

/* you need to decide just how far to take it */

.container {
    margin: 10px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 210px;
}

li {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: cyan;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Also, it is possible that you or other users might find [this helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331150/center-fluid-grid-of-elements-without-setting-hard-width-on-parent/8332101#8332101).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're looking for functionality similar to [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). It's kind of the same structure that Pinterest (if not **the** plugin) that Pinterest uses.

I don't think it's limited to oddly shaped elements, so should work out perfectly.

Comment: I have this set up at the moment https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3980495/5PORE/HTML/portfolio.html so I'm not looking for a content sorting plugin. Masonry seems to have the gap at the side as well but I suppose it's inevitable as its full screen.